# Image Preprocessing using keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to put a preprocessing function in ImageDataGenerator using preprocessing_function . The data was consists of images . I made a preprocessing image as follows .

```
def preprocessing(images):
    images = alignment(images)
    images = crop(images)
    return images
```

I had already checked this function with another image and it was working fine but it was not able to preprocess and train the model . The error came out to be - "Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image." . The error was directed to alignment function .

```
def alignment(image):
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # other stuffs
```

The error came in the first line of alignment function . Please help me .

Comment: Can you do a ```print(gray_image.shape)``` and ```print(image.shape)```, so I can see if it's a dimension problem

Comment: `print(gray_image.shape)` gives (150,150) while `print(image.shape)` gives (150,150,3) . I had even reshaped the gray_image to (150,150,1) but I got the same error .

Comment: If you are using just one example then convert the shape to (1, 150, 150) or (1, 150, 150, 1) for gray image; or  (1, 150, 150) or (1, 150, 150, 3) for RGB image

Comment: I had used preprocessing_function in keras . I don't think I need to reshape this into something like that what you said .